# Searching in arraylist<String[]> from user input

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to search in an arraylist from a user input but my if condition doesn't seem to work. Using boolean and .contains() doesn't work for my programme either. This is the coding:

```
String phone;
phone=this.text1.getText();
System.out.println("this is the phone: " + phone);

BufferedReader line = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Laura Sutardja\\Documents\\IB DP\\Computer Science HL\\cs\\data.txt")));
    String indata;

    ArrayList<String[]> dataArr = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

    while ((indata = line.readLine()) != null) { 

        String[] club = new String[2]; 
        String[] value = indata.split(",", 2);  
        //for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 

            int n = Math.min(value.length, club.length);
              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
               club[i] = value[i]; 
        }
          boolean aa = dataArr.contains(this.text1.getText());

          if(aa==true)
          text2.setText("The data is found.");
          else
          text2.setText("The data is not found.");

        dataArr.add(club);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.size(); i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < dataArr.get(i).length; x++) {
            System.out.printf("dataArr[%d][%d]: ", i, x);
            System.out.println(dataArr.get(i)[x]);
        }
    }


 }
 catch ( IOException iox )
{
  System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: Please describe in detail how it doesn't work. What errors do you see (show the logs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with the program. I assume you want to read a textfile and store each line in the arraylist. To do this you have to split each line of the textfile and store that array in the arrayList.

```
String[] value;
while ((indata = line.readLine()) != null) { 
    value = indata.split(",");
    dataArr.add(value);
}
```

Now you have the contents of the file in the arrayList.
Next you want to compare the userinput with each element of the arraylist.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.size(); i++) {
    String[] phoneData = dataArr.get(i);
    if (phoneData[1].equals(phone)) { // i am assuming here that the phone number is the 2nd element of the String[] array, since i dont know how the textfile looks.
        System.out.println("Found number.");
        club[j++] = phoneData[1];
    } else if (i == dataArr.size()-1) {
        System.out.println("Didn't find number.");
    }
}
```

Edit:
As requested:

```
    String phone;
    phone = "38495";
    System.out.println("this is the phone: " + phone);

    BufferedReader line = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("list.txt")));
    String indata;

    ArrayList<String[]> dataArr = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] club = new String[2];
    String[] value;// = indata.split(",", 2);
    while ((indata = line.readLine()) != null) {
        value = indata.split(",");
        dataArr.add(value);
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.size(); i++) {
        String[] phoneData = dataArr.get(i);
        if (phoneData[1].equals(phone)) {
            System.out.println("Found number.");
            club[j++] = phoneData[1];
            break;
        } else if (i == dataArr.size()-1) {
            System.out.println("Didn't find number.");
        }
    }
```

I hope this makes sense now.

Comment: the data in my text file is separated by a comma. I want each data to be stored separately.

Comment: Ok possible too, let me adjust my answer.

Comment: @LauraSutardja I am not saying my solution fixes all of the issues, but at least you can compare all the entries in the textfile with the userinput.

Comment: i am still confused as where to put the changes. can u place your solutions in the coding i posted?

Comment: @LauraSutardja i will update my question with all of your code.

Comment: I skipped the part on how you would get the userinput and replaced that with a fixed string as that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: This is the output i received:this is the phone: 77
Found number.
Didn't find number.

Comment: the number 77 does exist in my text data

Comment: @LauraSutardja Oh right, you might want to uncomment the `break;` in the `if` statement. Then it works. So that if it has found a match it breaks out of the for loop

Comment: @LauraSutardja i stored only the phonenumber in the club array, if you want that different and store the entire `dataArr` entry in the club array, change `String[] club = new String[2]` into `String[][] club = new String[2][2]` and assign it `int j = 0;`   `club[j++] = dataArr.get(i);`

Comment: @LauraSutardja please post a new question for this with some of the code you have produced so far. :)

Comment: it's working now! i didn't realise i put a space after the comma! :)

Comment: It's nice that you can work with your own file, but imagine if it's a (long) file with maybe less consistancy and splitting at a komma isn't going to work. How would you solve that...? Thats just one of the many problems you can encounter.

Comment: can u help me with the new question i just posted? :)

Comment: well in this case it is a small project so i guess maybe i wont have to encounter that problem. i hope i wont though. hahha:)

Answer (score 2):

Your `dataArr` is a list of `String[]`, and you are searching for a `String`. The two are different kind of objects.

I don't really know how the content of the `club` array looks like, but you should either change `dataArr` in order to hold plain `String`, or to write a method which looks iteratively in `dataArr` for a `String[]` containing the output of `this.text1.getText()`.